# Verifying Length of Integer

Tags: ruby

## Hello Everyone,

I have another Ruby question.
I want to make sure the users input is 5 numbers if its more or less I want it to output Error. I might have the loop wrong I sometimes get it confused.


Do I have to use Integer(gets.chomp)? 

Because I have seen that also when getting integers from users.

---

**Here is my code:**
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

```
print "What is your zip code? "
zip_code = gets.chomp
puts zip_code
zip_code_array = zip_code.split

unless zip_code_array.length == 5
  puts "Error"
else
  puts "Good"
end
```

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ZIP code is not an integer. It's a string of five digits.* For example, `00911` is a valid ZIP code (San Juan, Puerto Rico), but it is not an integer in any practical sense.

The correct solution, then, is not to check if the string is an integer of a certain size, but rather if it's a string of five digits.

A regular expression will make short work of this:

```
print "What is your zip code? "
zip_code = gets.chomp
puts zip_code

if zip_code =~ /^[0-9]{5}$/
  puts "Good"
else
  puts "Error"
end
```

In case you're not familiar with regular expressions, this one breaks down like so:

```
/
  ^     # beginning of line
  [0-9] # a digit 0-9
  {5}   # repeated exactly 5 times
  $     # end of line
/x
```

*Strictly speaking, a ZIP code can be five digits or five digits followed by a dash and four digits (ZIP+4). You'd be wise to accommodate both in your application.

Comment: Wow ok, this is code I have not work with yet. What does this do? =~ ? lol

Comment: that is regex match.

Comment: What does the "=~" mean?

Comment: `=~` is the [regular expression matching operator](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-3D-7E). If the regular expression on its right matches the string on its left it will return truthy; otherwise it will return falsey.

Comment: Oh ok, is that just how the code is or is there meaning behind using /^[ ]{ }$/

Comment: I don't understand your question. `/.../` in Ruby is a regular expression (Regexp) literal. The above Regexp certainly has meaning, and I've explained what each part of it does in the second part of my answer. You can get more information [in the Ruby docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Regexp.html) and [Regular-Expressions.info](http://regular-expressions.info). You'll encounter regular expressions frequently in Ruby and understanding their use is important to becoming proficient in reading and writing Ruby code.

Comment: HA! Oops, I see it now.

Comment: It's usually better to use `match` in preference to `=~` since it's a lot more self-explanatory and easier to search for. That operator was probably inherited from Perl, a language not necessarily known for its readability. Also try for `/\A[0-9]{5}\z/` instead of `^...$` since `\A` is guaranteed to be the beginning of the string, not just the beginning of a line, and the same with `$` vs. `\z` for end.

Comment: To accomplish the four digits and dash. Could that be done with an OR some how or is that not right?

Comment: @tadman We'll have to agree to disagree on `=~` vs. `match`. As for your second point, in this case OP is using `gets` so I'm content assuming the input contains no newlines.

Comment: @Scope You could, but you could just as well use a Regexp that matches both e.g. `/^[0-9]{5}(-[0-9]{4})?$/`.

Comment: @scope `x =~ y` and `x.match(y)` should be equivalent. What code are you using and what error are you getting?

Comment: @Jordan The "assume" part here is where people get into trouble. The Ruby community has been burned badly in the past by people forgetting to use `\A...\z` so it's something that should be strongly encouraged. In this particular case it might not matter, but in other cases it absolutely does so it's better to be safe here.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `zip_code_array = zip_code.split`

Only this will do

```
unless zip_code.length == 5
  puts "Error"
else
  puts "Good"
end
```

The problem is that the `split` method , splits the array based on spaces and you don't provide spaces when entering the zipcode. So the array length ends up being equal to 1.

Comment: may be at that time you were providing an input with spaces. Unless you want to work with regex, you can use other string methods e.g. `zip_code.gsub(' ','').length` to remove spaces before checking the length.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are split `zip_code` no need to do that you have to directly check string length.

```
print "What is your zip code? "
zip_code = gets.chomp
puts zip_code


unless zip_code.length == 5
  puts "Error"
else
  puts "Good"
end
```

when you split zip_code it will convert your entered string in to an array with one element (Ex. if you enter '123abc' then `zip_code.split` convert it in to ["123abc"] and it will give length = 1 every time)

you can write like below (Option 2):

```
print "What is your zip code? "
p gets.chomp.length == 5 ? "Good" : "Error"
```

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, does doing it this way benefit in any way then the other answers? Just wondering.